# Запретить перетаскивание файлов из finder на мак на input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить перетаскивание файлов из finder на мак на input
с аттрибудтом type="file"?
Пробовал скрипт ниже. Не получается. Возможно, этот код запрещает перетаскивание на элемент только дом узлов. А на файлы из finder не распространяется.

```
item.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вашего "ответа", который не является ответом, а дополнением к вопросу, во втором коде вы не указываете имя переменной для евента в стрелочной функции.

```
formWrapper.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
      let enableDragDrop = false;

      if (!enableDragDrop) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
   });
```

Comment: Благодарю. Точно подмечено.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось запретить перенос файлов из фаиндера вынеся код из обработчика событий для формы во внешнюю функцию

```
formWrapper.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler);

function dropHandler(event) {
let enableDragDrop = false;

if (!enableDragDrop) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

}

Не понял почему этот код не срабатывает, если его поместить в обработчике события следующим образом:

```
    formWrapper.addEventListener('drop', () => {
      let enableDragDrop = false;

      if (!enableDragDrop) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
   });
```

Comment: А вторая часть ответа разве отвечает на ваш вопрос? Если ваш вопрос не решён полностью, то а) подождите пока вам ответят б) задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Во втором коде вы создали стреьочную функцию, но не указали имя параметра, для евента, который вы в дальнейшем и хотите отменить.

Comment: А)) Точно. Что ж это я не доглядел. Спасибо